# Change grid dropshadow color over time in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Kinda new to WPF, all in all i wanted to make a bordeless main window with a dropshadow border that changes its color after i do something. I think i got most of it i just dont know how to access the DropShadowEffect inside the Grid. Anyways here is the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Listener.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStyle="None"     AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"     KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
    <Grid Margin="20" Background="White">
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect
              ShadowDepth="0"
              Color="Red"
              Opacity="0.9"
              BlurRadius="15.0" />
        </Grid.Effect>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the relevent event code

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ColorAnimation ca = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Red, Colors.Blue, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(ca, ???);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ca, new PropertyPath("Background.Color"));

    Storyboard stb = new Storyboard();
    stb.Children.Add(ca);
    stb.Begin();
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        this.DragMove();
}
```

So how do i get the dropshadoweffect inside this ColorAnimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give your `Grid` some name, say RootGrid

```
<Grid Margin="20" Background="White" x:Name="RootGrid">
    <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Red" Opacity="0.9" BlurRadius="15.0"/>
    </Grid.Effect>
</Grid>
```

and change `ColorAnimation` to animate `Color` of the `Effect` on RootGrid

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(ca, RootGrid);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ca, new PropertyPath("Effect.Color"));
```

**EDIT**

Or, if you choose to, you could achieve that effect in pure XAML as well

```
<Grid Margin="20" Background="White">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>                 
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation To="Blue" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.Color" Duration="0:0:4"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
    <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Red" Opacity="0.9" BlurRadius="15.0"/>
    </Grid.Effect>
</Grid>
```

Comment: works perfectly, as a future reference is it best to set a x:Name for every element that you plan on using in code?

Comment: You set name to identify specific element of your layout and whether you need if for Storyboard animation in code or XAML, ElementName binding or something else is up to you. When accessing control by name you need to be aware of [namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx) so for example you cannot access globally control by name from template or style

Comment: I was wondring is there a way to use a List to save the elements in there? Lets say i have 4 grids inside another grid can i save their names as something like gridList[0], gridList[1] etc. to itterate them later. Or do i need to create them programaticly with this/save them in a list at run time with a search function?

Comment: You can create `List<Grid>` and keep your references there. There's nothing stopping you but I would limit amount of code to absolute minimum and do as much as possible in XAML.